# Handling Code review in TFS 2018 update2 version

Tags: tfs, review, tfvc

I am using TFS 2018 update 2 version, and I have to implement continuous integration for a project.

For that, I need to add *code review* functionality before "check in" as a *check in policy*, but in TFS 2018 version, there is no such policy?!

**Question:** are there other ways to include "Code Review" as check in policy?

(We are using TFVC, not GIT).

Comment: Further to add on to this,i use TFVC and not GIT

Comment: Tried to rephrase your question to make it more readable. Please have a look, and see if you can add more information, like other things you tried/researched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent check-in without a review, you can use a check-in policy. Here's a custom check-in policy that requires code review before check-in:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ColinD.ColinsALMCheckinPoliciesforVS2013andVSO

**Install Instructions:**

1. Download the VSIX and install it.
2. In Visual Studio 2017, connect to VSTS or TFS and connect to a TFVC repository.
3. Open Team Explorer and click on the Settings tile.
4. In the `Team Project` section, click the `Source Control` link.
5. Click on the `Check-in Policy` tab.
6. Click "Add..." and add either `Code Review Policy` or `One Work Item Policy`
7. Click either policy and click "Edit..." to open the configuration page for the policy.

But I should point out that check-in policies are not security mechanisms, think of them as a reminder for the developer to send the code for check-in. Developers can easily override them.

If you really need to prevent any check-ins, you should deny check-in permission for developers, and have them send their changes to the manager using a code-review (or shelve set). The manager can then unshelve the changes and check-in after reviewing.

Comment: Hi Shayki, I also looked upon this Colins checkin policy but the main disadvantage of this is "The settings are specified by an admin and stored on the server - but the policies are evaluated in VS, so each developer needs to install the extension. The policy will fail if it's required by an admin but not installed on a user's machine"..

Comment: Hi Shayki, also can you let me know on how to integrate this Colin's check inpolicy with tfs. I have downloaded the same for VS2017 and how to proceed further. Do i need to install this downloadable in my machine and configure with TFS for the particular project?

Comment: @Mani I added Install Instructions in my answer, please check :)

Comment: @Mani Did you succeed?

Comment: Yes Shayki,it worked..Shayki i have another doubt on Agent Queue, mine is  a.net web application project and for this i have choosen .net Core CI build definition template. My doubt is iam able to see only two Agent queues. 1) Default and 2) MI-POOL , please let me know can i choose any of these agent queues and proceed

Comment: @Mani you can choose any queue if to the agent on the pool are have all your required tools for the build (like MSBuild etc.)

Comment: Hi Shayki, can you let me know how to handle .net web applications with CI /CD with TFS 2018...as i said i am using .NET core build template, my doubt is can we give the MSbuild arguments for deploying the web applications or it should be provided with publish artifacts for doing a deployment of web application

Comment: can you let me know how to handle .net web applications with CI /CD with TFS 2018...as i said i am using .NET core build template, my doubt is can we give the MSbuild arguments for deploying the web applications or it should be provided with publish artifacts for doing a deployment of web application